# Can't switch GitLab accounts for command-line Git

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitlab

This might be flagged as a duplicate, I've tried all the fixes in the similar questions that popped up on the search, but none worked.

Basically, I was using my company's GitLab account to do my pushing, but decided to switch to my personal account for some reasons. Except I can't find a way to do that.

The `~/.git-credentials` file doesn't exist, when I try to open it nano just gives me a new file. The `~/.git-config` file already contains my personal account's email and username (but no password), and my commits on the repository page on GitLab are attributed to my personal account. However, Git never asked for the password (so I doubt it's actually logged in). Also, the contributions aren't showing up on my personal Overview page (the little colorful calendar thingy), instead they are showing up on the previous account's Overview page.

I also tried these two (separately):

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper

git credential-cache exit
```

No changes whatsoever. Still letting me push without asking for credentials, and commits still showing up on the wrong account's Overview.

I checked out the git-credential-store [documentation](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential-store.html) as well (as suggested in a similar question), and for whatever it's worth, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is empty and `$HOME/.config/git/` doesn't exist either.

Someone else suggested going to Access Tokens on the GitLab website and deleting the corresponding token there, but it says "This user has no active access tokens."

I even tried ye olde uninstalling and reinstalling Git and it changed absolutely nothing.

I'm at my wits' end. Any idea where these darned credentials might be stored, or a way to force logout?

EDIT: A coworker partially fixed it for me. I had both accounts authenticated via SSH, and GitLab was only using the one I connected first, which was the corporate account.

I deleted both SSH keys, generated a new pair and this time authenticated only my personal account. It's working now. I wanted a way that I could switch between accounts (I have to use both) without having to re-authenticate via SSH every time, and if anyone still has an idea, I'm open to it.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS or SSH?  Have you read through the relevant portions of the [Git FAQ}(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq)?

Comment: The repos are cloned via SSH. Which is strange, because even then, the first time I pushed, it asked me for username and password. Only that time and then never again.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show `git remote -v` as a code block?

Comment: With ssh on Linux, you have a lot of options. Typically you'll run `ssh-agent` and let it store (and forward) keys, and `ssh-add -l` will list out all your current keys. If you need to add one, `ssh-add` will let you add it to the pile. There's an issue here though: many *servers* only listen to the first N keys, so that if you have many keys, you'll run through the allowed number with the wrong keys before you reach the right one. There's no standard solution to this, as far as I know.

Comment: With just two keys, though, you should be able to add both and things will Just Work, though you'll be handing over an extra key in at least one case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The repos are cloned via SSH. Which is strange, because even then, the first time I pushed, it asked me for username and password. Only that time and then never again.

That looks like HTTPS URLs though. Check that with a `git remote -v` inside the repository.
Any credential helper setting that you would manipulate would only influence HTTPS URLS.

It is is SSH, then you would need to change those URLS to use an ~/.ssh/config entry

```
Host <HostEntry>
   Hostname xxxx.xx.xx
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_second_key.pem
```

With the new URL being:

```
ssh <HostEntry>
```